# C++ program stops at function call

Tags: c++, function

I'm new to working with c++ so I'm having trouble finding where my error is located. When my code reaches the call `assignGate` it stops working. I tried my program with line removed and everything worked fine. So the problem is most likely in that function but I can't see anything wrong with it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    string code;
    int flight;
    int time; 
    string gate; 
    node *next; 
};

bool isEmpty(node *head);
void insert(node *&head, node *&last, string code, int flight, int time);
void remove(node *&head, node *&last);
void assignGate(node *&head, int gates);
void print(node *&head);

int main()
{
    int gates; 
    bool x = false;
    string code;
    int flight, time, gate; 
    node *head = NULL;
    node *last = NULL;
    cout << "Welcome to Gate Scheduler.\n";
    ifstream file("FlightList.txt");
    if (!file) {
        cout << "Unable to open text file. \n";
        cout << "Make sure file is in correct location then restart program. \n";
    }
    while (file >> code >> flight >> time) {
        insert(head, last, code, flight, time);
    }
    cout << "Please enter the max number of gates avaliable:";
        cin >> gates;
        assignGate(head, gates);
        cout << "\n";
    print(head);
    return 0;
}

bool isEmpty(node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

void insert(node *&head, node *&last, string code, int flight, int time) {
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->flight = flight;
    temp->code = code;
    temp->time = time;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (isEmpty(head)) {
        head = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
    else {
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
}

void remove(node *&head, node *&last) {
    if (isEmpty(head)) {
        cout << "The list is already empty \n";
    }
    else if (head == last) {
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        last = NULL;
    }
    else {
        node *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

void assignGate(node *&head, int gates) {
    int y = 0;
    int gate[6];
    node* temp = head;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        if (temp->time > 2300 || temp->time < 600) {
            temp->gate = "N/A: Plane lands outside of airport operating hours.";
        }
        else {
            for (y = 0; y <= gates; ++y) {
                if (gate[y] == NULL) {
                    temp->gate = y;
                }
                else if (gate[y] + 100 < temp->time) {
                    temp->gate = y;
                }
            }
            if (temp->gate != "0" || "1" || "2" || "3" || "4") {
                temp->gate == "All gate are full at this time";
            }
        }
    }
}

void print(node *&head) {
    node* temp = head; 
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        cout << "Flight " << temp->code << " " << temp->flight << " will be at gate " << temp->gate << "\n";
        temp = temp->next; 
    }

}
```

Comment: There's many things wrong with `assignGate`, but those are all basic C++ rules that can be solved via a good book.

Comment: Like I said I'm new to programming in C++ and my code isn't getting any errors when I debug it. So if you could it at least point me in the right direction to fix the error I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: What you input as 'gates' argument in 'assignGate' function? if the 'file' contains 1 row and you input gates value greater than 1, then 'assignGate' would be exited unexpectedly

Comment: 'gates' can be an integer from 2 to 5 and the 'file' contains 20 rows

Answer (score 1):

First off, you assume that array is zero initialized. It is not. You don't have  zeros in gate[]. You should value-initialize it  to make them zero.

```
 int gate[6] = {};
```

You really should check if gates are less than size of array.

Next,  your problem is in this part:

```
        else if (gate[y] + 100 < temp->time) {
                temp->gate = y;
            }
        }
        if (temp->gate != "0" || "1" || "2" || "3" || "4") {
            temp->gate == "All gate are full at this time";
```

`temp->gate = y` does not do what you think. It assigns to string a character with code stored in integer. Of course, if() would fail. But it would also fail because you wrote wrong operation.
`(temp->gate != "0" || "1" || "2" || "3" || "4")` equals to... `(temp->gate != true)` You should look at the table of operator priority to understand why.

And there is algorithmic mistake.. you never proceed with temp.. it stays same, you'll never reach exit from the while loop.

There might be other gotchas I  omitted, because they aren't essential to the current problem. I was focusing on the assignGate function

PS. This is not error , but is very very bad style:

```
bool isEmpty(node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

'head == NULL' is a bool expression. You can return it.

```
inline bool isEmpty(node *head) {
   return head == NULL;
}
```